# UserDefault not updating in main view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a simple counter application where the user can set a maximum number of patrons allowed in their place of business and when that number is reached they're given a notification that they're at maximum capacity. I'm using UserDefaults to store this data, however whenever I update the max number in the settings and return to the main view it's still using the previous max number. If I close the app and reopen it has the correct data. How do I make sure the data is being updated in the main view controller so it receives proper data?

### Code

ViewController.swift (main view controller)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    var counter = 0;
    var max = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "max");
    

    
    // Max patron alert function
    func showAlert() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Limit Reached", message: "Your place of business has reached maximum capacity, please stop patrons from entering until capacity dissipates.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default))
        
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var count: UILabel!
    
    @IBAction func increment(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if counter < max {
            counter += 1;
            count?.text = String(counter);
        }
            
        
        if counter == max {
            showAlert();
        }
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func decrement(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (counter == 0) {
            counter += 0;
        }
        else {
            counter -= 1;
        }
        count?.text = String(counter);

    }
    
    @IBAction func reset(_ sender: UIButton) {
        counter = 0;
        
        count?.text = String(counter);
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

SettingsViewController.swift

```
import UIKit


class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var mainViewController:ViewController?;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var maxOccupancy: UITextField!
    

    @IBAction func save(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let max = Int(maxOccupancy.text!);
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(max, forKey: "max")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        print(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "max"))
    }
    
    
    
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: `UserDefaults` is the wrong way to share data between controllers even if the value is going to be kept. And reading the value right back to print it is pointless. You **know** the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
var max = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "max")
```

is executed only once, when `ViewController` is created. (BTW: no need for semicolons in Swift). Whatever happens to `UserDefaults` afterwards won't be reflected in its value.

Replace the line with

```
var max: Int {
    UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "max")
}
```

so that every access to it actually goes out to fetch the value from `UserDefaults`.

These constructs are called "Computed Properties", explained [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html).

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you read the counter number only once when `ViewController` is allocated. You might try to re-read it when `ViewController` will appear on the screen:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        max = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "max")
    }
```

Also, no need to use `;` in every line's ending, Swift doesn't require it.